# I want to make two Card to flip at the same time in Qt QML

Tags: qt, qml

I want to make two Card to flipable when I click the button,but I can make it for one,I don't know how to do this at the same time?
just like this:

```
MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked:five.flipped = !five.flipped}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
MouseArea { 
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        five.flipped = !five.flipped
        six.flipped = !six.flipped
    }
}
```

Comment: someone has given me a right answer,which is the same to you,thank you very muck

Comment: Click in the checkbox near this answer to select it as the official answer to your question, @Sphinx